# Fixed-effects Poisson estimator using quasi-maximum likelihood

Tags: r, fixed, effects, panel-data, poisson

I am trying to run a fixed-effects Poisson Quasi Maximum Likelihood estimator on 3-dimensional(year, country, industry) Panel data.

The dependent variable is the number of patents(non-negative and non-integer) and the main independent variable is the deregulation(a dummy variable which equals 0 before the year deregulation was implemented and 1 starting from the implementation year), and I have some independent variables as controls(size and share).

I tried several packages and functions on R, and mostly ended up on `glm` and `feglm`, trying to run these regressions, which I would expect to give the same results, but they are different.

```
model1 <- glm(pt ~ dereg + size + share + 
                factor(year) + factor(country) + factor(industry), 
              data=pdata, family=quasipoisson)

library(fixest)
model2 <- feglm(pt ~ dereg + size + share, data=pdata,
                cluster=c("country","industry", "year"), 
                family=quasipoisson)
```

What is the difference between the two methods?

Which one is more reliable in this case, or is there a more suitable package that will allow to include all fixed effects and run quasi-Poisson estimator on the panel data?

Comment: I believe your `feglm` call should rather be `feglm(pt ~ dereg + size + share | country + industry + year, data=pdata, family=quasipoisson)` to correspond to that of the `glm`. However, the results might still be different. Since this is not actually a coding question you should ask on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that.

Comment: @laura, I just got this by searching for another similar quasi-poisson issue, the tradepolicy package has some functions that might be handy, but it uses base R, while fixest uses a different implementation that avoids collinearity for large fixed effects and you are clustering, so both the coefficients and the std errors may be different